# How to convert ctype dec8 from udp body to correct node string

Tags: node.js, parsing, udp, ctype

I have some problem with parsing udp packet.
Data packet part contains sequence of hex bytes. Like:

```
94 C2 82 FD A1 ....
```

This data contains format data by c-types.
In list of type exist dec8 and with this types a have problem.
In raw formats dec8 type looks like:

```
00000005E06BD600
00000005E0B82140
00000005E1046C80
00000005E150B7C0
00000005E2359980
00000005E281E4C0
00000005E3FF5D00
```

I don't know where floating points.
Maybe someone know, how i can parse floating point from this raw data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this package for all convertation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/dissolve